# Passar autenticação do usuário entre contextos diferentes

Tags: jsf, java-ee, jee

Tenho três projetos java web(.war) com contextos diferentes dentro do mesmo EAR.

Necessito que o usuário se autentique em uma aplicação e que depois eu trafegue esta informação dele entre os outros projetos.
Pesquisando um pouco encontrei algumas abordagens bem elaboradas como Single Sign On, porém não sei se é necessário usar algo tão complexo para este tipo de problema. 
Gostaria da opinião de vocês sobre qual abordagem usar.

**Ambiente:**
Aplicações em JSF usando JavaEE e servidor Wildfly

Comment: Já que vai utilizar em projetos diferentes, não seria o caso de guardar essas informações em um local físico, banco de dados por exemplo?

Comment: Pensei em uma abordagem que não envolveria dependencia de banco, como criar um bean @applicationscoped para controlar isso, visto que ele seria visível entre todos os projetos.

Comment: application scoped não sei se é a melhor escolha, é muito custoso o processamento e consumo de memória. não tive experiencias boas com esse contexto. ainda mais se tiver muitos usuários conectados.

Answer (score 1):

Você sabe como funciona o Single Sign On ? 
Vou falar de acordo com os protocolos OAuth e SAML, ambos na versão 2.0.
Vamos lá, vc vai ter uma terceira pessoa envolvida, um servidor de identidade, o na hora da autenticação o usuário não vai informar sua credenciais para sua aplicação e sim para o terceiro envolvido (seu servidor de identidade),
o mesmo vai validade as credenciais, funciono ? 
se sim ele deve gerar um token (chave de identificação única), e retornar esses token para o usuário, a partir de agora sempre que vc precisar dos dados do usuário basta enviar esse token ao servidor de identidade, pronto qualquer aplicação que ter esse token vai receber os dados do usuário, nisso vc garante que o usuário informe suas credenciais apenas uma vez.

Tem um produto muito bom para fazer isso, WSO2 IS
da uma pesquisada ai.
E lembre-se, qualidade sempre.